# Is there any way to get Azure Active directory group setting using Graph Api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to get the bellow Azure Active directory group setting value from Graph API. Could you please let me know how i will get it using Graph API?

$directorySetting["AllowToAddGuests"]

As of now i have tried with this, But this is not suitable for my requirement. So i need to get actual value from this setting $directorySetting["AllowToAddGuests"]

[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{id}?$select=allowExternalSenders](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/%7Bid%7D?$select=allowExternalSenders)

Answer (score 0):

You can find this from the [Group Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/groupsetting?view=graph-rest-1.0) collection (`/groups/{id}/settings`):

> Group settings control behaviors such as blocked word lists for group display names or whether guest users are allowed to be group owners.

*note that this is a nullable collection and many (if not most) groups will return an empty array*